# TFS 2013 Express Author Image

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, tfs

MSDN states:

> **Author images**: Use images to more easily see the author of each
>   commit. If your Git repo remote origin is in a TFS Git team project,
>   team members can specify their images in their TFS profiles.

I use git on TFS 2013 Express and I can't see my profile image on any of the commits, neither in TFS nor in VS 2013 history. All I get is the TFS default user image. I've filled git settings on VS 2013 and logged into TFS 2013 with my profile account. TFS is installed on a Windows 7 SP1 box and I've created all windows users to use in TFS.
I've noted that on TFS, in the commit details, it's authored and commited by the git user, and it's pushed by the TFS user. Isn't it supposed to show profile images both on TFS and VS 2013?
Here's the TFS user profile setup:[image]

Here's the TFS Commits page:
[image]

Here's the VS 2013 Branch history:

[image]

Comment: Screenshot of where you expect the image (but it isn't displaying) and the TFS configuration where you have specified your user image?

Comment: Thanks, Edward. I've edited the question and added some snapshots.

Comment: I think this works only with VSO for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I remember, the git avatar in TFS is not taken from your profile but from [gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/).

Edit: In fact, that's if you have enabled the option. Did you have it?

Comment: Thanks for replying, Philippe. That's not what MSDN states, as I mentioned in my question:  "(...)If your Git repo remote origin is in a TFS Git team project, team members can specify their images in their TFS profiles"  Also, I guess that could become weird if you have one TFS profile image and a different gravatar image.  What I understood from MSDN is Gravatar could help if you haven't defined a TFS profile user image (from MSDN: "Enable download of author images from 3rd party source also works for TFS Git team projects in cases where the author has not supplied a profile image.")

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for those who are interested.
In a reply from a Microsoft guy, when using TFS the only picture we can get for source control is by using Gravatar.